# Decorator with changeble arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I have a simple decorator that should print all functions arguments. And imagine we have some small functions and one wrapper for this function and would like to log this wrapper function.

The problem is that for some reason the arguments does not work and I get an error

How would you rewrite the function log_step so that it would allow us to turn off and on the parameter for printing function arguments?

```py
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def log_step(func, print_params = False):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tic = dt.datetime.now()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        time_taken = str(dt.datetime.now() - tic)
        print(f"function {func.__name__} took {time_taken}s")
        
        if print_params is not False:
            func_args = inspect.signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments
            func_args_str = ", ".join(map("{0[0]} = {0[1]!r}".format, func_args.items()))
            print(f"{func.__name__} arguments: \n==================\n{func_args_str} \n==================\n")        
        
        return result

    return wrapper

def _simple_inside_function(name:str, age:int) -> str:
    """
    Simple Inside function that prints your name and age
    """
    age = age + 10
    print(f"Hello {name}, who is {age} years old.")
    
    return age

@log_step(print_params = True)
def wrapper_print_name(config: dict) -> str:
    """
    wrapper function
    I am spider man
    """
    A =  _simple_inside_function(**config)
    return A
```

Comment: If you are getting an error, you might share what that error actually is.

Comment: In any case, don't use `is not` here; just use `if print_params: ...`.

Comment: or maybe if is true, nothing wrong with being explicit about conditional checks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's a more elegant way using `functools`, but as far as I know you need *three* functions for a decorator with parameters: (a) the decorator function, taking a parameter and creating (b) another function, taking the original function as parameter, returning (c) the decorated version of the function, taking the original function's parameter, calling the function with pre/postprocessing and returning it's result i.e.:

```
def log_step(print_params = False):
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ...
            return result
        return wrapper
    return inner
```

Only if the decorator does not take parameters, you do not need the outermost function. This may seem weird and inconsistent, but makes more sense if you consider `@deco func` being analogous to `func = deco(func)` and `@deco(args) func` being analogous to `func = deco(args)(func)`.
Consequently, if you want to use the decorators without parameters, you'd do this (note the parens):

```
@log_step()
def wrapper_print_name(config: dict) -> str:
```

---

If you want to go without the `()`, i.e.

```
@log_step
def wrapper_print_name(config: dict) -> str:
```

there's probably no way around abusing the same parameter for either the `print_params` or the function itself. That's pretty hacky, but `functools` seems to do the same for `lru_cache`, which can be used as `@lru_cache(size)`, `@lru_cache()`, or just `@lru_cache`:

```
def lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False):
    ...
    if isinstance(maxsize, int):
        ...
    elif callable(maxsize) and isinstance(typed, bool):
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`log_step` should be a function that takes a Boolean argument and *returns* a function that takes the decorated function and returns a wrapper. In other words, `log_step` is a function that *produces* a decorator `_`, which will be used to wrap the decorated function.

```
def log_step(print_params=False):
    def _(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            tic = dt.datetime.now()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time_taken = str(dt.datetime.now() - tic)
            print(f"function {func.__name__} took {time_taken}s")
        
            if print_params:
                func_args = inspect.signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments
                func_args_str = ", ".join(map("{0[0]} = {0[1]!r}".format, func_args.items()))
                print(f"{func.__name__} arguments: \n==================\n{func_args_str} \n==================\n")        
        
            return result

        return wrapper
    return _
```

You are currently defining a function that expects both a function and a Boolean values as arguments, but then only passing the Boolean value when you use it.

---

You could even use the value of `print_params` inside `log_step` to define one of two different functions, to avoid having to check the (unchanging) value of `print_params` every time your decorated function is called.

```
def log_step(print_params=False):
    if print_params:
        def _(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                tic = dt.datetime.now()
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                time_taken = str(dt.datetime.now() - tic)
                print(f"function {func.__name__} took {time_taken}s")            
                func_args = inspect.signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments
                func_args_str = ", ".join(map("{0[0]} = {0[1]!r}".format, func_args.items()))
                print(f"{func.__name__} arguments: \n==================\n{func_args_str} \n==================\n")        
        
                return result
            return wrapper
    else:
        def _(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                tic = dt.datetime.now()
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                time_taken = str(dt.datetime.now() - tic)
                print(f"function {func.__name__} took {time_taken}s")                   
                return result
            return wrapper
    return _
```

You would probably want to refactor this into something like

```
def log_step(print_params=False):
    def foo(func, **args, **kwargs):
        tic = dt.datetime.now()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        time_taken = str(dt.datetime.now() - tic)
        print(f"function {func.__name__} took {time_taken}s")
        return result

    def param_printer(func, *args, **kwargs):
        func_args = inspect.signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments
        func_args_str = ", ".join(map("{0[0]} = {0[1]!r}".format, func_args.items()))
        print(f"{func.__name__} arguments: \n==================\n{func_args_str} \n==================\n")

    if print_params:
        def _(func):
            @wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                result = foo(func, *args, **kwargs)
                param_printer(func, *args, **kwargs)
                return result
            return wrapper
    else:
        _ = @wraps(func)(foo)
    return _
```